# Unable to connect mule Anypoint Connectors Update Site

Tags: mule, connector

I'm trying to download object store.

I'm getting below error while connecting to Anypoint Connectors Update Site - https://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0

```
Unable to read repository at https://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are facing some ssl certificate issues, this usually occurs when your JVM truststore contains self-signed certificates (i.e. certificates not signed by a CA).

This case occurs when Java attempts to connect to another application over SSL (e.g.: HTTPS, IMAPS, LDAPS), it will only be able to connect to that application if it can trust it. The way trust is handled in the Java world is that you have a keystore (typically $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts), also known as the truststore. This contains a list of all known Certificate Authority (CA) certificates, and Java will only trust certificates that are signed by one of those CAs or public certificates that exist within that keystore.

But before jumping to conclusion do check **Case 1 and 2**

**Case 1 :** Check if the link is not blocked by your firewall

Do refer the [Mulesoft Doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/studio-update-sites#to-allow-connection-to-update-site-through-firewall)

**Case 2 :**  Simply update your java (this is easy way)

**Case 3 :** Download Certificate manually and add in Java's truststore

Refer this [link](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html) to know how to download certificate manually and this [link](https://connect2id.com/blog/importing-ca-root-cert-into-jvm-trust-store) to add the certificate to the truststore (you will need OpenSSL toolkit to transform the certificate to required format, it is described in the the mentioned link), and in case you are not familiar with different extension related to SSl certificate go check out this [SO answer](https://serverfault.com/a/9717/438576)